# How can i send object from one application to another in android

Tags: android

I want to send a list of object form a class that I have created through intent from one application, and get this list in one other.

I tried this :

```
Intent i = new Intent();

i=getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getString(R.string.package_app));

ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, list);

i.setType("text/plain");
```

And to get it i have done this :

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

ArrayList<MyClass> getList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

getList=(ArrayList<MyClass>)receivedIntent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

startActivity(i);
```

But i have an exception when i want to get the list

Comment: What exception are you getting? @eterpoir

Comment: AndroidRuntime(9041): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packageOfTheFirstApp.MyClass

Comment: You want to send Array of Serialize Object from One App to Another App ?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm trying to do @Herry

Comment: Plz post full stack trace from your log cat to in to question .

Comment: Check out how to implement Parcelable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/233048

Answer (score 1):

According to your stack trace you need to make the **MyClass** serializable.

Then you can pass the list of **MyClass** to second activity.

This can be as shown below:

```
class MyClass implements Serializable
{
//your implementation
}
```

In your 1st activity you need to do something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,secondactivity.class);

ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
i.putExtra("listdata",list);
```

In your 2nd activity you need to do something like this:

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

getList=receivedIntent.getSerializableExtra("listdata",null);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Initializing `getList` makes no sense if you assign another value in the next line.